# Jquery UI Draggable: Align helper to mouse position

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, draggable

With jQuery I have a draggable element. It's a div with a size of 200 x 40.
Of course the user can start dragging this div by clicking at variuos positions in the div.
What I want is when the startdrag event happens, the helper (clone) div will always be aligned to the cursor the same way, no matter where in the div the user started dragging.

So after the mousedown the helper's top and left values need to be the same as the mouses x and y. I've tried this using this coffeescript code:

```
onStartDrag: ( e, ui ) =>
    ui.helper.css
        left: e.clientX
        top: e.clientY

    console.log( e )
```

But it doesn't work and my guess is that this is happening because the values I put in are directly overwritten by the draggable plugin because of mouse movement..

Any ideas?

Comment: You should set a jsfiddle to let us see whats going on

Answer (score 39, accepted):

After trying Amar's answer and realizing that it screws up interactions with `droppable`, I dug deeper, and found that there is an option specifically to support this called `cursorAt`.

```
$('blah').draggable
  helper: ->
    ... custom helper ...
  cursorAt:
    top: 5
    left: 5
```

This places the top-left corner of the helper 5 pixels above and to the left of the cursor, and interacts correctly with `droppable`.

http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cursorAt

And let's give credit where credit is due. Thanks, jquery-ui mailing list archives!

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jquery-ui/Evb94G_QvNw

Comment: You are totally right! ( http://jsfiddle.net/vLmN5/ ), this built in method is better than doing it yourself in the start function.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. The positioning of this helper element was bugging me for a long time. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Try setting like this,

```
       start: function (event, ui) {
                $(ui.helper).css("margin-left", event.clientX - $(event.target).offset().left);
                $(ui.helper).css("margin-top", event.clientY - $(event.target).offset().top);
            }
```

Take a look at this [jqFAQ.com](http://jqfaq.com/) , it will be more helpful for you.

Comment: Almost! But the margin-left/top instead of the left/top did the job.. Here's how it worked for me: `marginLeft: e.clientX - $(e.target).offset().left` and `marginTop: e.clientY - $(e.target).offset().top`.. If you could edit your post I accept it.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a fix for this and it's very easy, if you are using the sortable plugin you can fix the helper position like this:

```
sort: function(e, ui) {
    $(".ui-sortable-handle.ui-sortable-helper").css({'top':e.pageY});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with @roverv.

This works fine form me.

[image: Example of my icon following the mouse cursor after scrolling the page]

```
$('.js-tire').draggable
      tolerance: 'fit',
      appendTo: 'body',
      cursor: 'move',
      cursorAt:
        top: 15,
        left: 18
      helper: (event) ->
        $('<div class="tire-icon"></div>').append($('<img src="/images/tyre_32_32.png" />'))
      start: (event, ui) ->
        if $(event.target).hasClass 'in-use'
          $('.js-send-to-maintenance-box').addClass 'is-highlighted'
        else
          $('.ui-droppable').addClass 'is-highlighted'
      stop: (event, ui) ->
        $('.ui-droppable')
          .removeClass 'is-highlighted'
          .removeClass 'is-dragover'
```

Answer (score -1):

This did the trick for me:

appendTo: 'body'

Like so:

```
$(this).draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
    appendTo: 'body'
});
```