# Jquery UI Draggable with Addition of CSS's Scale Transition Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

So, I am developing a responsive web tool that is built around the jQuery UI's Draggable function. There is also the use of CSS's transition: scale(X, Y) in there as well.

My issue is; When I scale an object inside of a container, the object is limited in the location of where I can drag it in the container. For a physical demo of this issue, please visit this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNoqyZ).

The code is very basic, in the fact that the only Javascript is as follows:

```
$(function() {

    $('.workspaceObjects').draggable({

        containment: $('#ui_workspace'),

    });

});
```

So, it appears to be more of a CSS issue, but it has been puzzling me for a while now, and it is something that needs to be fixed to allow further development of my web tool. What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: any particular reason why you're scaling the element?

Comment: Basically, the container's size is increased to give it a zoom in effect. The scale of the object would increase to 1 when zooming was done, but so that the content of an object, such as text and images is displayed in a smaller scale, the element has been given the scale property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using negative margin of `20px` for the draggable, and centered the `transform-origin` to keep it balanced.

```
#container_object {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    margin: -20px -20px
}
```

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpvBgJ

Comment: I noticed that the object jumps away from the mouse. How would I prevent this?

Comment: Have a look at this, might solve your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230437/jquery-ui-draggable-align-helper-to-mouse-position